# ArgumentError: Unknown key: :as. Valid keys are: :unique , :order, :where ........ in Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I am getting the following error while running `rake db:migrate`:

> ArgumentError: Unknown key: :as. Valid keys are: :unique , :order,
>   :where, :type

This is the model where I am getting error:

```
add_index :addresses [:addresable_type, :addressable_id, :main], :as => 'main_address'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change code

```
add_index :addresses [:addresable_type,:addressable_id,:main] , :as => 'main_address'
```

to

```
add_index :addresses,[:addresable_type,:addressable_id,:main] , :name => 'main_address'
```